# Let $A,B \subseteq X$. If $A \subseteq B$, then $(X\setminus B) \subseteq (X\setminus A)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let $A,B \subseteq X$. If $A \subseteq B$, then $(X\setminus B) \subseteq (X\setminus A)$.

Using a sort of diagram I can easily convince myself this is true. I assume I must use a proof by contradiction here, but I am not sure. At this point all I can think of is that this essentially says $A \subseteq B$, $B \subseteq X$, and, since $A\subseteq B$, then $a\in A$ and $a\in B$, but I feel like I'm just misleading myself by thinking of these. If I were to try and prove by contradiction, what would I assume? That $(X\setminus B) \subseteq (X\setminus A)$ is false? If I do this, I'm not entirely sure where that gets me. Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you define $B^X$?  Work with small examples first.  What if $A=\{1\}$ and $B=\{1,2\}$ and $X=\{1,2\}$?  Are you sure you didn't want to prove $A^X\subseteq B^X$?

Comment: I'm suspecting $\;A^X\;$ is a rather weird form to denote the complement in $\;X\;$ of $\;A\;$ ...

Comment: @JMoravitz In that case, I would say $B^X$ would be an empty set, because $B^X$ has been defined for me as the set $X-B$

Comment: @CreasyBear that is horribly confusing notation then.  $A^X$ is usually meant to denote the set of functions from $X$ to $A$.  $A^c$ is usually the notation for $X\setminus A$.  (Some people use $\overline{A}$, but this also has a different use as the closure of the set $A$)

Comment: @JMoravitz I apologize if it's confusing, that is the notation that has been given to me to indicate the complement of $A$ in $X$. As for the question, it appears correctly.

Comment: @CreasyBear Whoever or whatever gave you that notation either has some rather misterious use for it later, or else doesn't know much about basic, standard international set theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you denote $\;X\setminus B\;$ is, in my opinion, very confusing or even completely wrong, as almost anyone will understand $\;A^X\;$ as the set of all functions from $\;X\;$ to $\;A\;$ . Perhaps you meant $\;A^c\;$ instead?

Anyway, suppose $\;A\subset B\iff \;\forall\,a\in A\;,\;\;a\in B\;$ , so

$$w\in B^c\implies w\notin B\implies w\notin A\implies w\in A^c\implies B^c\subset A^c$$

Comment: So one can just assume $w\in B^c$?

Comment: @CreasyBear You *assume* that, and then you show that **also** $\;w\in A^c\;$ . That's how set inclusion is proved.

Comment: @CreasyBear yes.  In general, when dealing with proofs to show one thing is a subset of another, you can take an arbitrary element of the left-hand side and show that if it exists it must necessarily be an element of the right-hand side.

Comment: Many thanks for all the help and clarification on the notation! I am baffled as to why I would be given incorrect or uncommon notation for that...

Comment: @CreasyBear A pleasure, and thanks to JMoravitz for his valuable comments.